# Passing a prop to a child from parent with React and Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Gatsby newbie in here, so be patient with me. I'm building a very basic blog app with Gatsby and React. I have a landing page with a section where I display the latest 3 blog posts that were published. Until now, everything worked fine with the following code in my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import get from 'lodash/get'

import Bio from '../components/Bio'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import SEO from '../components/SEO'
import { formatReadingTime } from '../utils/helpers'

class BlogIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const siteTitle = get(this, 'props.data.site.siteMetadata.title')
    const siteDescription = get(
      this,
      'props.data.site.siteMetadata.description'
    )
    const size = 3
    const posts = get(this, 'props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges')

    return (
        <div className="container">
          <Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
            <SEO />
            <Bio />
            <section>
              <div>
                {posts.slice(0, size).map(({ node }) => {
                  const title = get(node, 'frontmatter.title') || node.fields.slug
                  return (
                    <div key={node.fields.slug}>
                      <h3>
                        <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
                          {title}
                        </Link>
                      </h3>
                      <p>
                        {node.frontmatter.date}
                        {` • ${formatReadingTime(node.timeToRead)}`}
                      </p>
                      <p
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.frontmatter.spoiler }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )
                })}
              </div>
            </section>
          </Layout>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BlogIndex

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        description
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          timeToRead
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            title
            spoiler
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

However, I would like to separate the latest blog posts section into a separate component (ex. `LatestBlogPosts.js`) and import it in my `index.js` file. Therefore, I copied the markup in a separate file, imported that file in my `index.js` and all of a sudden there is an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

I checked and logging `posts` from the newly created file also returns `undefined`. The `LatestBlogPosts.js` file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import {formatReadingTime} from "../utils/helpers";
import get from 'lodash/get'

class LatestBlogPosts extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const size = 3
    const posts = get(this, 'props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges')

    return (
      <section>
        <div>
          {posts.slice(0, size).map(({ node }) => {
            const title = get(node, 'frontmatter.title') || node.fields.slug
            return (
              <div key={node.fields.slug}>
                <h3>
                  <Link to={node.fields.slug}>
                    {title}
                  </Link>
                </h3>
                <p>
                  {node.frontmatter.date}
                  {` • ${formatReadingTime(node.timeToRead)}`}
                </p>
                <p
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.frontmatter.spoiler }}
                />
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default LatestBlogPosts
```

And the modified `index.js` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import get from 'lodash/get'

import Bio from '../components/Bio'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import SEO from '../components/SEO'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import { formatReadingTime } from '../utils/helpers'
import { rhythm } from '../utils/typography'
import LatestBlogPosts from "../components/LatestBlogPosts";

class BlogIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const siteTitle = get(this, 'props.data.site.siteMetadata.title')
    const siteDescription = get(
      this,
      'props.data.site.siteMetadata.description'
    )

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
            <SEO />
            <Bio />
            <LatestBlogPosts />
            <Footer />
          </Layout>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BlogIndex

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        description
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          timeToRead
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            title
            spoiler
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I can't seem to understand why `posts` returns `undefined` in the `LatestBlogPosts.js` file?

Comment: You're not passing your posts to the child component, and if you don't want to then you're also not fetching the posts within the child component. One of these should fix it for you.

Comment: That is, just pass `posts` as a prop to `<LatestBlogPosts />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this expression:

```
posts = get(this, 'props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges')
```

In your first example, `this` points to `BlogIndex`; in your second example, you've moved the expression to the `render()` method of `LatestBlogPosts`, so the expression will look for the data on that component.

You need to pass the posts to the child component as a prop:

```
<LatestBlogPosts posts={posts} />
```

And reference it in the child's render method:

```
{this.props.posts.slice(...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing `posts` to `LatestBlogPosts`. Try:

`<LatestBlogPosts posts={posts} />`

then in `LatestBlogPosts` you can access with `this.props.posts`.